The Push Pull Power Amplifier in IC 555
I am working on a project which involves the design of IC 555 timer. It includes an "output stage" power amplifier (pin 3),


 Doing some research I found on Wiki about this Amplifier, which looks like a Quasi Complementary Push-Pull type. Simulating it on MATLAB, I found the following DC characteristics for V_CC = +12 volts, V_EE = -12 volts.

 Clearly it is an inverting amplifier which should actually be fed from the output Q' of the SR latch. Am I on the right track? Cause I don't know how would it respond to the SR latch output. As of AC inputs, V_out is a (negative polarity) pulsating DC.
Image References
 1.First figure
2.Second figure by
WalterDvorak,
CC BY 3.0| Cropped from Original
 3. Simulink simulation results for different values of Vin vs Vout that I had plotted in Excel

Take look here https://cdn.evilmadscientist.com/KitInstrux/555/555_principles_rev30.pdf

Awe Kumar Jha - Hi, Where did those schematic images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

Awe Kumar Jha - Thanks for trying to help with the references. There are still 2 problems: (a) As I mentioned above, the links must go to the HTML webpage (.html) which displays the image (so that readers can see context), and not directly to the image (.jpg/.png/.webp etc). (b) If you copy from (or deep link to) an image from Wikipedia, they have their own additional licensing requirements, which exceed the minimal SE ones. So for the image you linked, you must follow the CC BY 3.0 license. Do you need help?

@SamGibson, I have changed the links to the webpages that contain those referenced images. I think this solves the problem.

@AweKumarJha - Thanks again for trying, but no, it doesn't solve the problems :( You have still linked to that image from Wikipedia (aka Wikimedia Commons) without providing correct attribution as required by the CC BY 3.0 license which applies to that image - that breaks the license terms of that image :( And the link to the source of the first image is a Google link. Do you need help?

@SamGibson, Thanks for your time and help. I read about CC licensed materials and how to do proper attribution. I hope NOW there should be no problem. BTW Internet is really becoming more and more bureaucratic everyday!

It's not a quasi complementary amp, that would have both output devices (one of which would be a Sziklai pair, the other could be a single transistor or Darlington pair) fed in phase (both would be fed from the collector of Q3). In this circuit Q3 is acting as a phase splitter, which is more like what you would see in a totem pole output such as TTL uses.
The output driver circuit does indeed invert, you can see it shown with an inverting symbol in this image from Wikipedia:

Also, what your schematic shows as \$V_{EE}\$ is not that, it's connected to the discharge and reset circuits. There is no \$V_{EE}\$ supply in a 555, it just has \$V_{CC}\$ and GND, so you shouldn't be simulating it with \$V_{EE}\$ = -12 V.

The Vee will not be -12V. In the NE555 it will be an internal node to drive the discharge transistor from internal output signal, and also to make the internal reset signal to force the output and discharge pin states.
It is also not a "power amplifier" in the sense you might think of it - it is just an inverting output buffer for the internal output signal, capable of high current drive.
